# Jquery Ajax always getting 0 in success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is form element in HTML -

```
<form name="remfrm" id="remfrm" action="profile/uploadaudio" method='post' enctype='multipart/formdata'>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="">        
        <div><strong>Add audio </strong> (optional)<strong> :</strong></div>
        <input type="file" name="remAudio" id="remAudio" onchange="uploadAudio()"  />
        <img id="imgLoader" name="imgLoader" style="display:none;" src='img/ajax-loader.gif' alt="loading..." />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my ajax funciton -

```
function uploadAudio() {    
    $("#remfrm").ajaxForm({
        target: '#remAudio',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    }).submit();        
}
```

And here is Ajax function calling -

```
public function uploadaudio() {
    /* rest of the work */
    echo "success";        
    exit();
}
```

Javascript function `uploadAudio()` always returns with the alert as `0` value. After some research, I have put `exit();` in ajax function call at the end. But still it is returning `0` value in success function. What's going wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `onchange="uploadAudio()"` is your javascript function and your are calling php function on your onchange event. that's the reason. call ajax page and put your code there.

Comment: The return value of uploadAudio will probably always be 0, because (I assume) $.ajaxForm().submit() returns that. I am unsure what you want it to return.

Comment: Can you show more of your PHP code? Do you call the PHP function? What do you get when you navigate to `profile/uploadaudio`? It should show `succes`. If not, there is a problem in your PHP code, for which we need more context.

Comment: uploadaudio is one controller function from Profile controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```
function uploadAudio() {
     var val = $('#remAudio').val();

     $("#remfrm").ajaxForm({
       target: '#remAudio',
       data:{key: val},
       success: function(data) {

       }
     }).submit();        
    }
```

And after getting data value in php file. Put below code in your php file.

```
<?php
echo $_POST['key'];
?>
```